# No JDK specified

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat

Я пытаюсь запустить проект  maven в среде  intelij idea comunity 2019. Данный проект является веб-приложением которое использует фреймворк spring. При за пуске я создаю следующую конфигурацию(поскольку intelij idea comunity 2019 напрямую не поддерживает appache tomcat я использую плагин SmartTomCat ):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама структура проекта выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался два раза запустить проект в первый раз проект собрался и запустился tomcat но по адресу http:/localhost:8080/restraunts  выдавало ошибку 404.
После безуспешных попыток я закрыл среду и через некоторое время попробовал снова но у меня теперь появилась ошибка No JDK specified.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в данной проблеме.

Answer (score 1):

Зайдите в File | Project Structure... и в подразделе Project укажите JDK, которым вы хотите пользоваться в вашем проекте для его сборки и запуска. Вот пример того, как это выглядит:
[image: Project Structure in IntelliJ IDEA]

Comment: Спасибо ошибка No JDK specified исчезла. Но теперь при запуске проекта
tomcat выдаёт:
The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Comment: @Novichok45 Это проблема с вашим кодом или с конфигурацией в `web.xml`, которых тут не видно.